# How to create a new system or board to be emulated by QEMU

Tags: qemu

I am new to QEMU, but to support a system modeling project, I try to figure out how to emulate a new ARM microcontroller(M33 based) SOC which is not on the supported system list. I have checked on the QEMU documentation: https://qemu-project.gitlab.io/qemu/about/index.html but was not able to find directions to construct and add a new system model. I would appreciate very much if someone can point me to the right documentation, or suggest steps I can follow to generate the new model for emulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no documentation for how to write new machine models for QEMU. The best advice is to look at the source code for an existing machine type that seems similar to the one you want to add. Avoid looking at machine types that have been added to QEMU a long time ago -- they are often written in an older style or using older APIs which are no longer recommended for new code.

As a very rough rule of thumb, you should assume that a new machine model is about as much effort as porting an operating system to that new hardware. (Roughly, a device model is about as much code as a device driver.) Depending on how much functionality you need, you may be able to leave some or many devices in your SoC unimplemented -- the absolute minimum is usually something like a UART and a timer. You'll need documentation of the SoC (technical reference manual or similar, with detailed descriptions of the devices down to the register level).

(Out of curiosity, what is the M33-based SoC?)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I did go through some source files in the QEMU GitHub page under HW, which can work for me as a starting point. Based on the effort estimates you provided, I surely just want to implement the minimum feature set. It will be great if there are some documented standardized functions to borrow, and perhaps this can be part of the extension in QEMU for future. By the way, the SOC that I was referring to was an in house ARM cortex-M33 based micro-controller with timers, ADCs, and PWMs. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest using [Renode](https://renode.io/) rather than Qemu as it's better suited for microcontrollers and it's well documented and actively maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/renode/renode).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I look into the features of Renode and found it appears to be easier to use than QEMU which will require quite a bit of coding and re-building to add a device. However, if I want to do system level simulation which includes analog/physical components (e.g. transistors, R, C ), co-simulation with other tools is required. I was able to find some simulation interface for QEMU, but not yet for Renode. Do you see options to address this type of system modelling? Thanks.

Comment: @tchan Renode supports co-simulation with Verilator if you have Verilog code. I believe the case you describe would require some additional integration code, which would most likely be quite easy, but is not available off the shelf

Comment: QEMU is also actively maintained. Can you clarify why renode is better suited to microcontrollers?